# Standard notation for free product of family of groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation

Is there any standard notation for a free product of a family of groups?

For two groups, free product is usually written as $G_1*G_2$.

How about for a family of groups $G_i$ for some index set $I$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The [free product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_product) is the coproduct in the category of groups. Thus you could use
either $\coprod_{i \in I} G_i$ or $*_{i \in I} G_i$